# Know start and end point of a CGPathAddArc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cgpath

I want to know the start and endpoint of the arc generated with the `CGPath` method `CGPathAddArc`.

I want to draw a portion of an "ring" and think to do it combining two arcs with different radius and drawing two lines connecting the start and end points.

```
CGPathAddArc(anillo, NULL, centro.x, centro.y, r1, ang1, ang2, YES);
CGPathAddArc(anillo, NULL, centro.x, centro.y, r2, ang1, ang2, YES);
```

[image: geometry figure i want to draw]

Answer (score 2):

How about using arcToPoint instead

```
void CGPathAddArcToPoint (
  CGMutablePathRef path,
  const CGAffineTransform *m,
  CGFloat x1,
  CGFloat y1,
  CGFloat x2,
  CGFloat y2,
  CGFloat radius
);
```

You get to specify the start and end points which sounds like what you want.